# C# Parsing text file to extract specific line

Tags: c#, file, parsing

I have a text file which contains lot of data each on new line
but i want to extract the lines, which start with the values:

coordinates=(111,222,333)

There are several instances of this line and i would actually want to extract the part "111,222,333"
how can i do this?

Comment: Downvote, I cant see any problem here ... no research whatsoever ... No code extract that has failed to work ...

Comment: i need help on how to get it done.. im new with c#... so i dont know what needs to be done..

Comment: Regular expressions! Anyway if every line is like that you can simply parse each line (like a naive .INI parser).

Comment: So basically for each problem you have you are going to post a question, so that we code the answer for you ?

Comment: if ur not interested.. just ignore it..

Answer (score 4):

Something like

```
var result = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\test.txt")
    .Where(p => p.StartsWith("coordinates=("))
    .Select(p => p.Substring(13, p.IndexOf(')') - 13));
```

The first line is quite clear, the second line filters for only the lines that starts with `coordinates=(`, the third line extract the substring (13 is the length of `coordinates=(`)

`result` is an `IEnumerable<string>`. You can convert it to an array with `result.ToArray()`

Comment: Thats one way to go, but if you need more flexibility (like variable length so e.g 1,22,333 gets recognized) you could use `RegEx`. EDIT: Just saw you did it with the `IndexOf`, but still `RegEx` is mor flexible (but also more complex)...

Comment: thanks.. but what if there are string which are of more than 13.. coz there are certain -ve coordinates too..

Comment: @chrfin I don't see the problem in my code... It DO supports strings like coordinates=(1,2,3). The 13 is only the length of `coordinates=(`, not of `111,222,333`

Comment: @Fahad.ag: Then `RegEx` is maybe really the way to go, as you can search for your exact pattern pretty easy and no matter whats before it...

Answer (score 3):

```
var text = File.ReadAllText(path);
var result = Regex.Matches(text, @"coordinates=\((\d+),(\d+),(\d+)\)")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => new
        {
            X = x.Groups[1].Value,
            Y = x.Groups[2].Value,
            Z = x.Groups[3].Value
        })
        .ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 But, as a sidenote, this will preload the entire file in memory and then split it... It couldn't be feasible and it could be better to Regex it line-by-line.

Comment: @xanatos It's just for simplicity. You can of course invoke it line by line.